# PHP keeps skipping to 144, but when echoed, is correct value

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to get all pixel data inside of an image, and return it in JSON after encoding an Array. However, when I try to insert the $y data into the array, it always inserts 144. No in-between, always 144. When I echo $y, however, I get "0, 1, 2, etc."

$x, $r, $g, and $b are correct.

Any ideas? Here's my code:

```php
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    
    class PixelData {
        private $ar = array(
            "pixeldata" => [
                
            ]
        );
        
        public function getPixel($x, $y, $im) {
            echo $y; // echoes "0, 1, 2, 3, etc."
            global $ar;
            $ar["pixeldata"][$x]["x"] = $x;
            $ar["pixeldata"][$x]["y"] = $y;
            $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
            $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
            $ar["pixeldata"][$x]["r"] = $r;
            $ar["pixeldata"][$x]["g"] = $g;
            $ar["pixeldata"][$x]["b"] = $b;
        }
    }
    
    $src = "D:\Pictures\Test.png";
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($src);
    $size = getimagesize($src);
    $width = imagesx($im);
    $height = imagesy($im);
    
    for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++)
    {
        for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++)
        {
            $pd = new PixelData();
            $pd->getPixel($x, $y, $im);
        }
    }
    
    $js = json_encode($ar);
    
    echo $js;
?>
```

Comment: Your array is basically one-dimensional, because the only variable aspect is `$ar['pixeldata'][$x]`; you're never adding `$y` as another dimension. So, every time you increment `$y` in the inner-most `for` loop to go to the next level of `$height` you're overwriting the previous `$x` values. Basically, by the time your script is done, `pixeldata` will only contain the data of the top-most row of pixels, therefore they're always `144`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate further on my comment:

> Your array is basically one-dimensional, because the only variable aspect is `$ar['pixeldata'][$x]`; you're never adding `$y` as another dimension. So, every time you increment `$y` in the inner-most for loop to go to the next level of `$height` you're overwriting the previous `$x` values. Basically, by the time your script is done, pixeldata will only contain the data of the top-most row of pixels, therefore they're always `144`.

I also didn't notice until now, but if you wanted to store the data within the `PixelData` private array, you can't create a new instance within the `for` loops, you'd need to do that outside of the `for` loops.

This is probably what you want. As you can see, I've added an extra dimension to you pixeldata array, so as to include both `$x` and `$y` dimensions.

```php
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    
    class PixelData {
        private $ar = array(
            "pixeldata" => [
                
            ]
        );
        
        public function getPixel($x, $y, $im) {
            echo $y; // echoes "0, 1, 2, 3, etc."

            // Instantiate an array for this pixel
            $this->ar["pixeldata"][$x][$y] = [];

            $this->ar["pixeldata"][$x][$y]["x"] = $x;
            $this->ar["pixeldata"][$x][$y]["y"] = $y;
            $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
            $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
            $this->ar["pixeldata"][$x][$y]["r"] = $r;
            $this->ar["pixeldata"][$x][$y]["g"] = $g;
            $this->ar["pixeldata"][$x][$y]["b"] = $b;
        }
        
        public function getAr() {
            return $this->ar;
        }
    }
    
    $src = "D:\Pictures\Test.png";
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($src);
    $size = getimagesize($src);
    $width = imagesx($im);
    $height = imagesy($im);

    $pd = new PixelData();
    
    for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++)
    {
        for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++)
        {
            $pd->getPixel($x, $y, $im);
        }
    }
    
    $js = json_encode($pd->getAr());
    
    echo $js;
?>
```